# NServiceBus 3.3.3 doesn't throw exception when queue doesn't exists

Tags: nservicebus

I have a problem with migrating big project from NServiceBus 3.0.3 to 3.3.3.
The problem is: we have a lot of tests, that expect exception to be thrown if destination queue doesn't exist. This was true for 3.0.3, however, in 3.3.3 messages just go to "Transactional dead-letter messages" queue without exception thrown. I tried to search in NServiceBus github and debug it's code, but still can't get what change causes this behavior.

Is there a way to configure new NServiceBus client so it still throws QueueNotFoundException when destination queue doesn't exist?

**UPD:** While debugging NServiceBus code, I figured out that somehow it catches the exception thrown in System.Messaging.dll. I can't really tell where this happens, because dll seems to be optimized and I can't set breakpoints in a lot of places, but if I enable "Break on CLR Exceptions" I can see that it actually happens.

Comment: I haven't looked at the code, but what if you configure MsmqTransport.UseDeadLetterQueue = false?

Comment: 1. Can't really understand where to configure this. It seems like it's possible only through config files and there is no public property to do this in code.

2. In 3.0.3 UseDeadLetterQueue was definitely true, I checked this while debugging.

Comment: Yes, it's in the config.  I'm hoping setting this to false will bubble up the exception.  Since this just sets Message.UseDeadLetterQueue you could set up a quick test outside of NSB to see what happens.

Comment: Ok, I found an easy way to turn off dead letter messages:
config.Configurer.ConfigureProperty<MsmqMessageSender>(t => t.UseDeadLetterQueue, false);

BUT: it didn't help. Nothing appears in dead-letter queue and no exception is thrown on send to non-existing queue. Message is lost. Seems like my problem is not gonna be solved without rewriting tests.

Comment: About test outside NSB: it's pretty useless, because I alreeady figured out that MessageQueue class itself THROWS exceptions in situations I'm talking about. It's NSB who CATCHES them without rethrow. I think this article tells what they have changed
https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/issues/364

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure if this was an MSMQ issue or not.  Does the fix in the article help you?

Comment: No, it's actually the change that made our tests fail, I think :)

Comment: The only other thing would be a custom fault handler, but if the exception is getting eaten, that probably won't work.  You may have to modify the tests albeit undesirable.